# Changing navigation property relationships and deleting collection items in disconnected generic enviroment

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have the following two classes that are able to internally track all changes.

```
 public class Agent
  {
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public ICollection Roles { get; set; }
    public ICollection DeletedCollectionItems { get; set; }
    public ICollection NewCollectionItems { get; set; }
    ChangeTrackingState State { get; set; }
    ....
  }
  public class Role
  {
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public ICollection Agents { get; set; }
    public ICollection DeletedCollectionItems { get; set; }
    public ICollection NewCollectionItems { get; set; }
    ChangeTrackingState State { get; set; }
    ...
  }
```

1) When an navigation property is set if it was previously set then the original object is added to DeletedCollectionItems and the new object is added to NewCollectionItems.

2) When objects are added or deleted from a collection they also update the relevant collection e.g. when a role is removed from Agent.Roles the role is added to DeletedCollectionItems.

My problem is:

Using EF in a disconnected environment I have to 'replay' all the changes when I attach my root entity (Agent) back to the context. If I'm updating an existing Agent and I've removed a role how can I recreate the relationship that is currently in the database and delete it so that the change is reflected in the database when I call SaveChanges?

I need to do this in a generic way so that I'm not duplicating code and can simply pass and object as the root object. I have based my implementation of Julie Lerman's ApplyChanges method

```
private static void ApplyChanges<TEntity>(TEntity root)
  where TEntity : class, IObjectWithState
{
  using (var context = new GeniusContext())
  {
    if (root.IsNew)
    {
      context.Set<TEntity>().Add(root);
    }
    else
    {
      context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(root);
    }
    foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker
      .Entries<IObjectWithState>())
    {
      IObjectWithState stateInfo = entry.Entity;
      entry.State = ConvertState(stateInfo.State);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```